# Mock user in spring secutity reactive application

Tags: spring-security, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-test, jwt

I have a spring application that uses the following dependencies:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>    

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-tools</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The security application is configured as following:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("myAuthority")
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> converter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor());
    return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
}

static class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<String> authorities = (Collection<String>) jwt.getClaims().get("roles");

        if(authorities == null) {
            authorities = List.of();
        }
        return authorities.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

}

so I need authenticated user to request the api and the authority `myAuthority`.

I would like to write some tests for this to be sure a test fails if someone changes the security configuration.
I use this:

```
    protected WebTestClient webTestClient(Object controller) {
    return WebTestClient.bindToController(controller)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .configureClient()
            .build()
            .mutateWith(mockJwt().authorities(new SecurityConfiguration.GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor()));
}
```

but all tests pass and no authenticated user is needed nor authority. 
**I would like to use `@MockUser` to test roles.**

***EDIT for further info on tests***

here is the test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@Import({MyRepository.class, ValidationConfiguration.class})
public class MyControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MyController controller;

    @Test
    public void test() {}

}
```

Comment: Is your TestClass annotated with @SpringBootTest oder @WebFluxTest?

Comment: I don't use SpringBootTest but I use WebFluxTest

Comment: If I use `@SpringBootTest` with `@WebFluxTest`  I have this error `found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith`

Comment: SpringBootTest is configured to load/boostrap whole configurations. WebFluxTest only configuration of Controller. All other Classes or Configuration should be mocked. If you also wanna test SecurityConfiguration, use ```@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@Import({ SecurityConfiguration.class })``` Do not combine both.

Comment: I tried and I am getting this error now : Failed to load ApplicationContext `Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChain'` `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.ReactiveJwtDecoder' available`

Comment: Did someone ever get to solve this? I get the exact same error.
Seems pretty hard to wire spring normal security(not reactive) to webflux test.

Comment: we use this


`private WebTestClient webTestClient(Collection<String> expectedRoles)
    {
        return WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build()
                .mutateWith(mockJwt().jwt(builder -> builder
                        .claim("username", "username")
                        .claim("roles", expectedRoles))
                        .authorities(new SecurityConfiguration.GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor()));
    }`